# ParametricPlot and ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

Using ParametricPlot and ContourPlot , plot the function $ x=g(y) $ in $ -6\leqslant y\leq 6 $ where $ g(y)=\frac{y}{2}cosy+\frac{1}{2} $. How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ContourPlot[x == y/2 Cos[y] + 1/2, {x, -2, 3}, {y, -6, 6}]
```

[image]

alternativly: `ParametricPlot[{y/2 Cos[y] + 1/2, y}, {y, -6, 6}]`

Comment: axes x and y are upside down right?

Comment: @AliciaRoberts Yes